Change legend and x-axis title in workshop chart
As stated I can't find a way to edit the legend and the x-axis title of a chart in workshop module. How can I do it?
Chart in workshop app - screenshot

There seem to be no options to:

Change the default legend names
Change the default x-axis title

thank you

you need to try and test more to view all options available on the right panel.
you can change axis titles as well as legend text and colors.
for axis title click on show title and change title

for the second axis you have to open it

and for legend you need to open the chart series and scroll down to legend section

here you can change legend title

I hope it helps
